# Check if the name is in database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table, which includes 16 car names. I want to change the font color and size if a car's name is found in a database.

This is my table:

[image]

And this is my PHP code for the first three cars:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
if (!$connection){
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("cars", $connection);

$carname="car";
$squery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM marks WHERE care_name=$car_name ");
echo"<div class='cars'>";
if(mysql_fetch_array($squery))  {
    echo"<r><strong>". $row['car1'] ."<strong></r>";
}
else{
    echo"<p>". $row['car1'] ."</p>";
}
echo"</div>";

echo"<div class='cars'>";
if(mysql_fetch_array($squery))  {
    echo"<r><strong>". $row['car2'] ."<strong></r>";
}
else{
    echo"<p>". $row['car2'] ."</p>";
}
echo"</div>";

echo"<div class='cars'>";
if(mysql_fetch_array($squery))  {
    echo"<r><strong>". $row['car3'] ."<strong></r>";
}
else{
    echo"<p>". $row['car3'] ."</p>";
}
echo"</div>";

?>
```

However, this doesn't work, it makes only on the first car (`car1`).

Comment: Where is `$car_name` supposed to come from?

Comment: Sorry, I just had to ask. Are those misspellings intentional?

Answer (score 2):

You are using variables such as $row without assigning it a value first.
You need to save the return value from `mysql_fetch_array` into the `$row` variable e.g.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($squery);
if($row){
...
}
```

EDIT: On further examination of your code, it contains multiple basic errors such as

- using variables that are not given a value;
- you use a different name each time you access the car from $row (at
  least I hope this is a coding error and not that you have 16 columns 
  in your database table, one for each car...);
- if mysql_fetch_array fails, you still try to print the contents
- You are writing code for each individual mysql_fetch_array instead of
  using a loop

and there are probably many others. You really need to improve your basic understanding of coding practices (and possibly databases) before we can help further, as there are too many basic errors here that show a lack of understanding of what you are trying to do

Comment: thank you for your help. Actually I have only one column. And I am very beginner, so you are right I have to improve my coding skill! But I need really to do this code as soon as it is possible. 

Can you please tell me how to make a loop, or how to do this coding? I'll be grateful :)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm unable to teach you the basics of coding in a comment! I assume this is for a course you are doing, so you will have course material to cover these topics. You will also find tutorials on PHP, SQL and whichever database you are using (MySQL I presume).

Comment: Atually my code works, exept for it changes the font color and font size of BMW, if I insert whatever of those car marks? and if I insert second car mark fer example Sab, it changes Tyota's font??

Comment: @Misia, this code *can't* work, and if it appears to be working its certainly not working correctly - you use uninitialised variables which haven't been given a value; at no point do you save the return value of mysql_fetch_array so you can actually use it to print it out the results; your logic is all wrong - you still try to print the car returned by the call even if the call fails (and therefore no car would be returned)... Unless the code you're using is different to the code above?

Comment: @Misia some advice when you're learning to develop code - start with only a few lines of code for one part and concentrate on getting it working first before adding any more code. The extra code makes it more difficult to track down where the problems lie. e.g. start by getting your query to work, then add the loop to go through results, only then worry about formatting the appearance.